# Javascript two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a two dimensional array in a javascript function.  I found code that should do that but doesn't.  I declare the array then define a function to add elements to the array which are also arrays.

```
    // Array function
    var card_array = new Array();
    function card_array(card_id, card_top, card_left) {
        alert('array');
        this.card_id = card_id;
        this.card_top = card_top;
        this.card_left = card_left;
    }

    // Toggle LinkCard minimize/expand
    function toggle_linkcard(toggle, card_id) {

        var icard = 0; 
        $('.linkcard').each(function () {
            card_top = $(this).position().top;
            card_left = $(this).position().left;
            card_i = $(this).attr('id');
            card_array[card_array.length++] = new card_array(card_i, card_top, card_left);
            icard++;
        });
        alert(card_array);

    }
```

The line of code where I add elements to the array breaks the code.

```
            card_array[card_array.length++] = new card_array(card_i, card_top, card_left);
```

What should I fix in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the function's name as `card_array`, same name as the variable's. So after that line of code, you don't have any variable named `card_array`, only the function. Try changing your variable or function name.

Comment: Also, you can eliminate some code clutter by doing a `card_array.push()` instead of `card_array[card_array.length++]`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you have two values with the same name: card_array

- A variable named which is initialized to a `new Array()`
- A function which takes 3 parameters

The function declaration happens last and hence wins.  So when you execute the expression `card_array[card_array.length++]` you are doing so on a function instance, not an array.

To fix this change the function name to a unique name.

Comment: That was the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line:

```
var card_array = new Array();
```

into:

```
var my_card_array = new Array();
```

And this one:

```
card_array[card_array.length++] = new card_array(card_i, card_top, card_left);
```

into:

```
my_card_array.push(new card_array(card_i, card_top, card_left));
```

And of course, change the alert.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed the variable name and switched to .push().  This works.